# Python: what's the subtraction value between two time.time()?

Tags: python, time, timestamp

```
import time

print time.time() - time.time()
```

the result unit is `millisecond` or `second`?

what I want do is judge if the two operation time span is larger than 10 minutes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number. (from [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time#time.time))

So difference between two times is also seconds.

```
time_a = time.time()

# ... some operations ...

ten_minutes =  10 * 60
time_span = time.time() - time_a
if time_span > ten_minutes:
    # time span is larger than 10 minutes.
```

Comment: **seriously?** you could not just write `ten_minutes = 600`?

Comment: @InbarRose Now what if you want 722,3 minutes? I think it's a perfect example to use `10 * 60`

Comment: `ten_minutes` seems to me like a very specific variable name which corresponds to a very specific amount of seconds, I don't think it needs the extra math, it is more like a constant. If you *are* going to use a variable time to check duration of time, then you should not call that variable `ten_minutes`

Comment: 10 * 60 become 600 after byte compile. Try dis.dis(lambda: 10*60).

Comment: I agree that `ten_minutes` is too specific name. But OP did not said about the purpose the 10 minutes, I just used ten_minutes. Any suggestion for alternative name?